# basic geometry terminology question

Tags: terminology

Imagine a square, take two sides and bring them together to form a triangle, is there a name for the distance between the point and the now unused line of the former square? It must be a specific percent of the line length, the "???" ratio maybe? If there is a name for that length, is there a specific name for a rectangle made of long lines and short lines made of the "???" ratio of the long lines?